# Why isn't iPhoto '11 showing an event present in the library?

Tags: photos.app

I'm having a problem where the last imported photos to my iPhoto '11 (version 9.1.5 (615)) library don't show up under the "Events" entry. The event shows up under "Last import" and under "Photos", but not under "Events". I have tried to re-create the event several times, without luck. There are several events created from the last two photo imports that aren't showing under "Events".

What can I do to fix this problem? Is there a way to reset iPhoto's "Event" index somehow so it can be rebuilt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the problem only was that I had managed to sort the events "manually" (View > Sort Events > Manually) which hid the newly created events in-between my rather large amount of existing events. Sorting by date (View > Sort Events > By Date + Descending) shows my new events first in the list as they should.